# Chrome not showing save password prompt with Angular 2

Tags: html, google-chrome, angular

It works on Firefox, but Chrome doesn't prompt to save password. 
Here is my code

```
<form  (submit)="verifyLogin()">

      <div class="login-data">
                <div id="test">
                 <p id="pTest">Username</p>
                 <input type="text" id="loginTest" name="username">
                 </div>

               <div id="test">
               <p id="pTest">Password</p>
               <input type="password" id="loginTest" name="password">
               </div>

      </div>
      <button class="loginButton" type="submit">Ok</button>
      <button  class="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
      </form>
```

At the moment is empty. I use it only to hide the login part and show the next page

```
verifyLogin(){
        this.showMeLogin = true;
        this.showFirstPage = false;

    }
```

Comment: can you post also your ts code